# Trying to figure out how to dynamically change which array is used for a label based on combo box selection?

Tags: c#, winforms

So I'm unfortunately a bit of a super noob at the moment haha so please bear with me if possible.

The program that I'm attempting to make is a piano note randomizer for the sake of memorizing notes/scales efficiently. I thought it'd be a fun little program to aid in both my piano journey and programming journey haha.

[image: Image of Program]

So with the program, I've put a combo box that has an option for every piano scale which looks like this:

[image: picture of combo box]

I then went ahead and made an array for each of the scales and the notes for that scale like so:

```
 //Arrays to store each scale
            string[] cMajor = { "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "A", "B", "C", };
            string[] dMajor = { "D", "E", "F#", "G", "A", "B", "C#", "D", };
            string[] eMajor = { "E", "F#", "G#", "A", "B", "C#", "D#", "E", };
            string[] fMajor = { "F", "G", "A", "Bb", "C", "D", "E", "F", };
            string[] gMajor = { "G", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F#", "G", };
```

I then used a random number generator to use as the index for the arrays so that it would randomly select a number between 0 and 7 which would ideally select an array index at random which we could then pass into a label which would be the piano note that is displayed on screen.

```
//Number Generator to pass into the newNumber variable which will act as an index for the array
            Random generator = new Random();
            int newNumber  = generator.Next(0, 7); // Generating a number that equates to the number of notes in a particular scale
```

I then entered code to check the combobox for the selected input, which would then create the label based off of what scale is selected:

```
 if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 0)
            {
                OUTPUTLABEL1.Font = new Font("Segoe UI", 100);
                OUTPUTLABEL1.Location = new Point(80, 5);
                OUTPUTLABEL1.Text = cMajor[newNumber];

            }
```

Everything works as intended for the most part. I can select the scale and the note pops up on screen, the issue is that NONE of this is dynamic lol. The scale selection is hard-coded into the program as you can see. And the scale of cMajor is also hardcoded as well.

The idea is that I can select a scale from the ComboBox and the text will dynamically change based on what scale is selected in the ComboBox. The only way I can think of to acomplish this would create a ridiculous amount of redundant if statements and I feel like there's probably a better way I could accomplish this.

Thank you guys so much and once again I do apologize if this is obvious or any other mistake that I might've made. This is my first post here and I hope that I've provided enough information for you guys! Thank you again!

CODE IN IT'S ENTIRETY (Ignore the timer):

```
        public void RandomizeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            //Arrays to store each scale
            string[] cMajor = { "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "A", "B", "C", };
            string[] dMajor = { "D", "E", "F#", "G", "A", "B", "C#", "D", };
            string[] eMajor = { "E", "F#", "G#", "A", "B", "C#", "D#", "E", };
            string[] fMajor = { "F", "G", "A", "Bb", "C", "D", "E", "F", };
            string[] gMajor = { "G", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F#", "G", };

            //Number Generator to pass into the newNumber variable which will act as an index for the array
            Random generator = new Random();
            int newNumber  = generator.Next(0, 7); // Generating a number that equates to the number of notes in a particular scale

            if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 0)
            {
                OUTPUTLABEL1.Font = new Font("Segoe UI", 100);
                OUTPUTLABEL1.Location = new Point(80, 5);
                OUTPUTLABEL1.Text = cMajor[newNumber];

            }

            if (TimerCheckbox.Checked)
            {
                seconds = int.Parse(timeInterval.Text);
                timer1.Start();
            }         
        }
```

If my way of thinking with arrays and combo boxes is less than ideal then I'm open to an entire new solution if needed! Thank you guys so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question and code cover a few related areas:

- Dynamically change which array (of notes) is used for the label based on combo box selection.
- Use the `Random` class correctly to implement the Randomize function.
- Automate the Randomize button with a timer.

Ok, you did say **I'm open to an entire new solution if needed!** so this answer *will* explore other ways to go about these three things and give you a couple new skills to try out. In particular, if you learn how to use Data Binding early on (as shown in this sample) it's likely to accelerate everything else you ever do in WinForms.

[image: screenshot]

---

**Binding the Scales to the ComboBox**

One approach is to define a `class` that represents a Scale. This associates the information more tightly than a dictionary lookup would. The `ToString` method will determine what's shown in the combo box.

```
enum ScaleForm { Major, Minor }
enum Key { A, B, C, D, E, F, G }
enum Signature { Natural, [Description("\u266F")] Sharp, [Description("\u266D")] Flat }
class Scale
{
    public Key Key{ get; set; }
    public ScaleForm Form { get; set; }
    public Signature Signature { get; set; }
    public string[] Notes { get; set; } = new string[0];
    // Determines what displays in the ComboBox
    public override string ToString()=> $"{Key}{Signature.ToUnicode()} {Form}";
}
static class Extensions
{
    public static string ToUnicode(this Signature signature)
    {
        switch (signature)
        {
            default: return string.Empty;
            case Signature.Sharp: return "\u266F";
            case Signature.Flat: return "\u266D";
        }
    }
}
```

Next make a list of `Scale` objects that will be the dynamic source of the combo box:

```
BindingList<Scale> Scales = new BindingList<Scale>();
```

Initialize the individual scales *and* the list of scales in the method that loads the main form.

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm() => InitializeComponent();

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        Scales.Add(new Scale
        {
            Key = Key.C,
            Notes = new[] { "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "A", "B", "C", },
        });            
        Scales.Add(new Scale
        {
            Key = Key.D,
            Notes = new[] 
            { 
                "D", "E", 
                $"F{Signature.Sharp.ToUnicode()}", 
                "G", "A", "B", 
                $"C{Signature.Sharp.ToUnicode()}", 
                "D", 
            },
        });
        Scales.Add(new Scale
        {
            Key = Key.E,
            Notes = new[] 
            { 
                "E", 
                $"F{Signature.Sharp.ToUnicode()}", 
                $"G{Signature.Sharp.ToUnicode()}", 
                "A", "B", 
                $"C{Signature.Sharp.ToUnicode()}", 
                $"D{Signature.Sharp.ToUnicode()}", 
                "E", 
            },
        });
        Scales.Add(new Scale
        {
            Key = Key.F,
            Notes = new[] 
            { 
                "F", "G", "A", 
                $"B{Signature.Flat.ToUnicode()}", 
                "C", "D", "E", "F",
            },
        });
        Scales.Add(new Scale
        {
            Key = Key.G,
            Notes = new[] 
            { 
                "G", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", 
                $"F{Signature.Sharp.ToUnicode()}", 
                "G", 
            },
        });
        Scales.Add(new Scale
        {
            Key = Key.B, Signature = Signature.Flat, 
            Notes = new[] { 
                $"B{Signature.Flat.ToUnicode()}", 
                "C", "D", 
                $"E{Signature.Flat.ToUnicode()}", 
                "F", "G", "A",
                $"B{Signature.Flat.ToUnicode()}"},
        });
        comboBoxScales.TabStop= false;
        comboBoxScales.DropDownStyle= ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
        // Attach the list of scales
        comboBoxScales.DataSource= Scales;
        // Initialize the value
        onScaleSelectionChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        // Respond to combo box changes
        comboBoxScales.SelectedIndexChanged += onScaleSelectionChanged;
        // Respond to click randomize
        buttonRandomize.Click += onClickRandomize;
        // Respond to automated timer checkbox changes
        checkBoxTimer.CheckedChanged += onTimerCheckedChanged;
    }
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Also in the same method, the event handlers are attached. For example, when a new scale is chosen in the combo box, the first thing that happens is that the label is set to the root.

```
private void onScaleSelectionChanged(object? sender, EventArgs e)
{
    labelCurrentNote.Text =
        ((Scale)comboBoxScales.SelectedItem).Notes[0];
}
```

---

**Using the `Random` class**

You only need one instance of `Random`. For testing, you can produce the *same* pseudorandom sequence of numbers every time by seeding it with an int, e.g. `new Random(1)`. But as shown here, the seed is derived from the system clock for a different sequence every time you run it.

```
private readonly Random _rando = new Random();
private void onClickRandomize(object? sender, EventArgs e) =>
    execNextRandom(sender, e);
```

One implementation would be to get a number between 0 and 7 inclusive, and use it to dereference an array value from the current selection in the combo box. This also makes a point of getting a *new* note on every click so the user feels confident when they click.

```
private void execNextRandom(object? sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string preview;
    do
    {
        // Randomize, but do not repeat because it makes
        // it seem like the button doesn't work!
        preview =
            ((Scale)comboBoxScales.SelectedItem)
            .Notes[_rando.Next(0, 8)];  // Will never return 8!
    } while (preview.Equals(labelCurrentNote.Text));
    labelCurrentNote.Text = preview;
}
```

---

**Automated timer**

One of the easier ways to get a repeating function is to make an async handler for the timer checkbox. There's no need to start and stop a Timer or handle events this way, but it still offers the advantages of keeping your UI responsive by 'not' blocking the thread except for when the new random note is acquired.

```
private async void onTimerCheckedChanged(object? sender, EventArgs e)
{
    while(checkBoxTimer.Checked) 
    {
        execNextRandom(sender, e);
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds((double)numericUpDownSeconds.Value));
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow! This is fantastic, thank you so much for taking the time out to show me all of this stuff. I'm obviously still trying to learn, so some of these concepts I haven't quite learned just yet, but I really appreciate you pointing me in the right direction! These are all things that I'll absolutely make a priority of!

Comment: Oh for sure! We're all here to learn and it never really ends. I'm not clear if you were able to get this code running at all? If it helps, I have my testing code on my GitHub repo and you could just [clone](https://github.com/IVSoftware/scale-randomizer.git) it and play around with breakpoints and such. Let me know if any questions arise. Fun for me, btw, but full disclosure I'm a _drummer_ not a musician haha.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want a linked data structure. The most common method to have a map between one variable and another is to use a Dictionary

```
//you can use a dictionary
public Dictionary<string, string[]> scalesDict = new Dictionary<string, string[]>() {
        {"a", new string[]   { "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "A", "B", "C", } },
        {"b", new string[]  { "D", "E", "F#", "G", "A", "B", "C#", "D", } },
        {"c", new string[]  { "E", "F#", "G#", "A", "B", "C#", "D#", "E", } },
        {"d", new string[]  { "F", "G", "A", "Bb", "C", "D", "E", "F", } },
        {"e", new string[]  { "G", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F#", "G", } } };
private string[] GetScale(string comboBoxValue) {
    return scalesDict[comboBoxValue];
}
```

the above code would get you your array based on the combobox value (replace a,b,c,d, and e with whatever your combobox uses)

dictionaries are very powerful tools in c#

Your question was a bit vague though, so I'm not sure if I've fully covered your issue, let me know

Comment: Those are "scales" not "chords".

Comment: @Wyck good thing this isn't musicoverflow lol, fixed my method for you

Comment: It is also possible to initialize the dictionary from the existing `string[]`s of note names.  e.g.:  `new Dictionary<string, string[]>() { {"cMajor", cMajor}, {"dMajor", dMajor}, /*etc.*/ }`